# QT different style for File explorer on Windows OS

Tags: qt, qml

I'm new to QT/QML so please be gentle with me.
I'm writing a function in existing QT application that opens File Explorer. I've tried FileDialog QML Type, but it opens in a native Windows style.
I'm looking for a different style (more like a GTK file chooser as in the picture below).
Is there a way to do it for a Windows application?

Thanks a lot!

[File explorer style example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjM1D.png)

Comment: Did you try to change a style? See [Styling Qt Quick Controls guide](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-styles.html) for more info.

Comment: Yes, tried QQuickStyle::setStyle("Material"). It doesn't change the look of the File Explorer

Comment: Ok, I guess that the only way is to implement your own.